# Unity Android Unable to login into Facebook after first try

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I got the facebook to work in Unity with android but after the first time i log in it doesn't work anymore. I think it's because i don't log out but i don't know why it doesn't stay logged in either so i can use the API. Here is my code :

```
public class FacebookLogin : MonoBehaviour {


void Awake()
{
    if (!FB.IsInitialized)
    {
        FB.Init(InitCallback, OnHideUnity);
    }
    else
    {
        FB.ActivateApp();
    }
}

private void InitCallback()
{
    if (FB.IsInitialized)
    {
        FB.ActivateApp();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK");
    }
}

private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
{
    if (!isGameShown)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}

public void FBLogin()
{
    List<string> perms = new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" };
    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);
}

private void AuthCallback(ILoginResult result)
{
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;

        FB.API("/me?fields=first_name", HttpMethod.GET, getName);
        FB.API("/me/picture?type=square&height=128&width=128", HttpMethod.GET, getProfilePic);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Main_Menu");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
    }
}

private void getName(IResult result)
{
    LocalDataBase.Name = result.ResultDictionary["first_name"].ToString();
}

private void getProfilePic(IGraphResult result)
{
    LocalDataBase.profilePicture = result;
}
```

}

Can someone please explain to me how do i save the login token or does it save automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to save the FB token. Whenever you want to use it, you can get it from these lines of code:

```
string token = null;
if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
{
    token = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
}
//... use the token here onwards...
```

Comment: Do i need to save the FB.IsLoggedIn or does it save automatically when i close the app so i don't need to do anything else?

Comment: No need to keep FB.IsLoggedIn either. Everytime you run the app, call initialize and on InitCallback, make the login request. Since the user would have already granted permission to those login parameters previously, no popup would show and you would be able to use the same flow as when user was using it the first time.

Comment: So in fact i didn't need to save the access token.

Comment: Yes, there is no need to keep track of it. Facebook SDK would do it for you

Comment: When you say i just login using        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback); even after i granted permissions? Sorry for being silly it's the first time i have to deal with this. Last time i tried loggin in again it gave me an error saying the key hases were wrong

Comment: See, FB.IsLoggedIn is your friend. All I meant was that if the user already granted permission, nothing noticable would happen if you called FB.LoginWithReadPermissions, except some delay due to a network call. That said, if you are logged in, i.e. FB.IsLoggedIn is true, you have an access token and you are free to make any request to FB, provided its been granted permission before.